# Running an ASP.NET Web Application on Apache with Mono

Tags: asp.net, apache, mono, web-applications

I have developed an ASP.NET web application that has the following files (after being published):  Default.aspx, Web.config, .dll (in  bin folder), .pdb (in bin folder), and an App_Data folder that currently has nothing in it.  This application runs well in Visual Studio.

My company uses Apache so the IT department decided to try Mono to run my application.  Unfortunately, the application does not run.  A question that was asked of me was where the .cs file was located.  Out of the output files, after publishing, I cannot seem to find the .cs file that the .aspx file is suppose to refer to.  Am I missing a file out of the list that I provided above?

Also, does anyone know soem rules of thumb or processes for getting an ASP.NET web application to run through Mono.  I just need some direction.

I really appreciate everyone's feedback on this.

Thank you,

DFM

Comment: publishing a site does not copy the .cs files, they are in your Visual Studio Project's folder. It might be possible for unwanted users to download your source code otherwise.

Answer (score 7):

You need to install **mod_mono** on Apache. There is more information about this on the [Mono ASP.NET page](http://mono-project.com/ASP.NET). The `.cs` is compiled into the DLL is not needed at run-time.

Comment: +1, but I don't know about that last part- will he need to re-compile his .cs file using mono?

Comment: And does Mono 'play' nice with Web Site's instead of Web Applications?

Comment: Mono is binary compatible with .NET, so the .cs files are not necessary. The latest releases of Mono also fully support compiled web applications and web sites.

Answer (score 3):

The .cs files would be compiled into the DLL, so they are not needed for deployment.  Other than that, we would probably need some more information to figure out why the app won't run under Apache/Mono.